# Как удалить или переименовать поля класса при наследовании

Tags: c#, ооп

У меня есть класс машина и класс электромашина. Дело в том, что класс электромашина наследует от класса машина поле `Fuel` и мне ее нужно удалить или переименовать просто потому-что у электромашины нет топлива а есть заряд.

```
class Car
{
    public int MaxSpeed = 180;
    public int Range = 100;
    public int CurrentSpeed = 100;
    public int Fuel = 100;
    public void Drive()
    {
        if (Fuel <= 0)
            throw new Exception("Not enough fuel");
        else
        {
            this.Fuel--;
            Range -= Range / CurrentSpeed;
        }
    }
}
class ElectroCar : Car
{
    int Charge;
    public ElectroCar()
    {
       Charge = base.Fuel;
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему бы не сделать поле которое лишнее просто приватным, не уверен про C# но в С++ такое легко делается, тогда у класса потомка это поле не будет доступным.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul: Сделать-то такое можно. Вопрос не в этом. Вопрос в смысле наследования: производный класс должен быть _разновидностью_ базового. А электрическая машина не является разновидностью машины с топливом.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Никак.

Если у класса-предка есть поля, не имеющие смысла в классе-потомке, то вы неправильно выстроили иерархию наследования.

Есть разные пути исправить ситуацию. Например: выделите *общее* у `Car` и `ElectroCar` в базовый класс `Vehicle`, `Car` переименуйте в `FuelCar`, и свойства, относящиеся к топливу, пускай содержит только `FuelCar`.

Comment: тоже раньше об этом думал, думал есть альтернатива, спасибо!

Comment: @Duoxx: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @Duoxx, поправка: не `CarBase`, а `Vehicle`. Ведь выделенные общие черты можно наследовать не только для различных видов автомобилей, но и для троллейбуса, к примеру.

Comment: @Duoxx поддерживаю Arhad, правилнее `Vehicle`, тогда и упряжку с осликом тоже можно наследовать.

Comment: А почему не сделать `Fuel`  свойством - `Fuel {private get; private set;}` ?

Comment: @Сергей: Потому что у электрической машины его вовсе не должно быть.

Comment: Можно же абстрагироваться от топлива и энергии, сделав ,например, интерфейс источник питания

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk: Можно и так, да, композиция вместо наследования. Я описал простейший вариант (и даже специально написал, что есть разные пути).

Comment: @VladD приватные поля же не наследуются, только protectet и publick internal

Comment: @Сергей: Вопрос не в внешнем интерфейсе. Поля Fuel в классе ElectroCar не должно быть вовсе. Если вы обратитесь к классу через ссылку на родительский класс, поле «проявится».

Answer (score 1):

Я предлагаю добавить перечисление Source

```
enum Sources
{
    Gas,
    Diesel,
    Petrol,
    Kerosene,
    Electricity   
}
```

Поле fuel заменить на powerSource типа Sources и добавить поле числовое powerIndex которое характеризует числовой показатель расхода энергии

Comment: Идея-то хорошая. Но вопрос, в каких единицах `powerIndex`? А если у нас гибридная машина, нужно два `powerIndex`'а? Не, если уж переходить к композиции, сделайте `PowerSource` полноценным интерфейсом, и пусть каждая имплементация работает по-своему.